# Mysql INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY Reinsert with new key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
INSERT INTO data(data_uuid, ...) VALUES(uuid_v4(), ...);
```

I have read about [on duplicate update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) but what I am looking for instead of updating the existing column is to reinsert the row with an updated uuid. Is there any constructs that can make life barer-able here?

I keep hitting such an error :

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0f7018da-4df5-4e22-b995-3b3c3e4e85d3' for key 'data_uuid'
```

To resolve it temporarily I am padding the UUID however I would like to have cleaner solution that still keeps me with the UUID.

The uuid function looks like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_v4() RETURNS char(36) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    SET @h1 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h2 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h3 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h6 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h7 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h8 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h4 = CONCAT('4', LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0x0fff)), 3, '0'));
    SET @h5 = CONCAT(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 4 + 8)),
                LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0x0fff)), 3, '0'));
    RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(
        @h1, @h2, '-', @h3, '-', @h4, '-', @h5, '-', @h6, @h7, @h8
    ));
END
```

Comment: The chances of a uuid v4 collisions are mostly zero.

Comment: That's why it's called _universally unique_ :-)

Comment: If you have collisions issues, you should check your system RNG, update your system. Mostly a software problem then a real probability of collision.

Comment: Use BEFORE INSERT trigger and update `NEW.data_uuid` if duplicate is detected.

Comment: I think you basically want `INSERT IGNORE` + `SHOW WARNINGS`, though it'd be cleaner to solve in the application side, typically with a try/catch construct that detects key violation and grabs the replacement data. However I fail to understand the overall logic. If key is, as it seems, irrelevant by itself, how is this different from just leaving it blank and getting it generated upon insert (e.g. with a trigger)?

Comment: If you want guaranteed uniqueness, use `auto_increment`.  For almost everyone else, a `UUID` is sufficient.

Comment: @EliasSoares I have some edits to show the type of error I keep getting. I am trying to insert some few million entries in the database.

Comment: Even with a few million entries it should be unique safe

Comment: Can you show us the function you use to generate the UUID on mysql? Can this function be moved outside mysql?

Comment: @EliasSoares see the function above

Comment: @Bwire please check updated answer.

Comment: MySQL has a [builtin function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that function is for UUID v1, not v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, if you are getting collisions with UUID with just a million rows (yes, just) that's because your random uuid generation is using some weak random generator.

Since you now posted your `uuid_v4()` function, and it relies on MySQL `rand()`, I can explain why your code is failing.

According to mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way
>   to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between
>   platforms for the same MySQL version.

This means that you can't use mysql to generate your uuid, at least not with `RAND()` function.

You will need to generate the uuid outside mysql of possible. There's a few libraries for it in many languages:

- PHP: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid
- Java: https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid
- Javascript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Always check if the library you choose uses a Cryptographically-safe random generator.

## UPDATE

It's possible to generate safe UUID V4 on MySQL side using [`random_bytes()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes) function:

> This function returns a binary string of len random bytes generated using the random number generator of the SSL library.

So we can update your function to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_v4s()
    RETURNS CHAR(36)
BEGIN
    -- 1th and 2nd block are made of 6 random bytes
    SET @h1 = HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(4));
    SET @h2 = HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(2));

    -- 3th block will start with a 4 indicating the version, remaining is random
    SET @h3 = SUBSTR(HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(2)), 2, 3);

    -- 4th block first nibble can only be 8, 9 A or B, remaining is random
    SET @h4 = CONCAT(HEX(FLOOR(ASCII(RANDOM_BYTES(1)) / 64)+8),
                SUBSTR(HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(2)), 2, 3));

    -- 5th block is made of 6 random bytes
    SET @h5 = HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(6));

    -- Build the complete UUID
    RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(
        @h1, '-', @h2, '-4', @h3, '-', @h4, '-', @h5
    ));
END
```

This function should be safe enough to use without care about collisions unless you have a very massive row count.

## Test

I've created following test scenario: Insert random UUID v4 as primary key for a table until 40.000.000 rows are created. When a collision is found, the row is updated incrementing `collisions` column:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (uuid) VALUES (uuid_v4()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE collisions=collisions+1;
```

The sum of collisions after 40 million rows with each function is:

```
+----------+----------------+
| RAND()   | RANDOM_BYTES() |
+----------+----------------+
|       55 |              0 |
+----------+----------------+
```

The number collisions in both scenarios tends to increase as number of rows grows.